# MySQL conditional statement on NULL with subquery

Tags: mysql, performance, conditional-statements

**Two tables:**

```
user (id, myValue, ...)

user_preferred (id, userid, preferredValue) fk userid -> user(id)
```

**Explanation:**

user is a table of all users.  user_preferred is a table of any user's preferred values.  A user can be listed multiple times in user_preferred but must have different values.  Query should return all users that have a myValue that matches the preferred value of the given user.  $userid is the php variable of the user passed.

**The Trick:**

A user could have no preference, in which case there is no entry in the user_preference table.  When the above query is done, I want to return every user if the given user has no preference.

**Analogy:**

I'm at a bar and the bartender asks me what I want to drink.  I say give me everything he has that matches my preference.  The first round I say I like crappy beers.  So he gives me a Fosters.  Second round I say I have no preference and he gives me 12 pints ranging from Bud Light to Guinness.  Instead of beers, these would be users.  Get it?

**Query (so far):**

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE
IF ((SELECT preferredValue FROM user_preferred WHERE userid = $userid) IS NULL, 
   1, 
   user.myValue ANY (SELECT preferredValue FROM user_preferred WHERE userid = $userid)
)
```

**Additional Trick:**

I don't want to run "SELECT preferredValue FROM user.preferred where id = $userid" twice.  Can I save the results from the first run-time and somehow use it in place of the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return a list of users:

```
SELECT o.*
  FROM `user` o
 WHERE o.id IN
     ( SELECT DISTINCT m.userid
         FROM user_preferred m
        WHERE EXISTS 
              ( SELECT 1 FROM user_preferred p
                 WHERE p.preferredValue = m.preferredValue 
                   AND p.userid <> m.userid 
                   AND p.userid = $userid )
     )
    OR ( o.id <> $userid AND NOT EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM user_preferred q
            WHERE q.userid = $userid
         )
       )
```

Comment: It needed a little tweak but that's it.  Many thanks, Spencer.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT *,(SELECT preferredValue FROM user_preferred WHERE userid = $userid) AS Result FROM user WHERE

IF (Result IS NULL,1,RESULT)